# Android Chromecast support MediaRouter drawable resource issue

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-cast-api, mediarouter

Recently began upgrading Google's CastCompanionLibrary from v2.5.2 to the latest v2.9.1. Apparently v2.5.2 relied on android-support-v7-mediarouter-v22.2.1, while latest v2.9.1 has a gradle dependency for mediarouter-v25.0.0. All is well, until this drawable resource seems to be missing in gradle-sync and/or gradle-compilation.
"No resource found that matches the given value '@drawable/ic_media_route_off_mono_dark'". What are the alternatives, and what are the solutions? Please don't suggest, I should not be using a mediarouter library drawable resource in my Project code-base to begin with.

Comment: Why not just add the image yourself? I'd suggest downloading it and adding it your project, it's really easy to find that image online, I found with my first google search.

Comment: I'd rather use Google's recommended image resource, or an upgraded resource with a different file-name as an alternate, than copy a third-party library image resource, and forget to upgrade it later.

Comment: Well, I of course meant to use the icon that comes from Google directly and their icon guide has it, as well as I found it under their GitHub for google code samples.

Comment: Are you referring to Google's Material Design Icons on github?